# Spring Security + Angularjs redirect after login

Tags: angularjs, spring-security

Trying to use idea from this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().and()
            .logout().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/main.html", "admin.html",  
            "/login.html", "/")         
            .permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

Also I use angularjs ngRoute:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'main.html',
              controller: 'MainController'
        })
        .when('/admin', {
          templateUrl: 'admin.html',
              controller: 'AdminController'
        })
        .when('/login', {
          templateUrl: 'login.html',
          controller: 'LoginController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

And so on.

But when I try to open admin page (for example /#/admin) it opens login form (from the box) and after that I expect that **it should redirect me** back to /#/admin, **but it redirect me** to /admin.html, which is out of the angular control.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To address the /error redirection you can create a controller like this

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/error")
    public String error() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }

}
```

from a spring-boot perspective it should always fall in index.html where you are "giving the control to angular"

Im assuming your resources folder structure is as follows
resources/static/index.html

so that index gets rendered when accesing root.

My directory structure is diffent than the one on the tutorial but it should work

Just Understood what your problem is: 
So in your angular config add this :

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('#');
```

and in the index.htm include the base tag

```
  <base href="<!-- @echo BASE_URL -->" target="_blank">
```

this will get rid of the '#' charecter and everything should work

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand something, but Spring Boot gives error for this solution : "There is already 'ErrorController' bean method". And of course I have no others methods ErrorController written by myself, that's why it means that it is Security bean from the box which control mappings for /error. Am I understand right?

Comment: Just edited my response, i think your problem is in the angular config